# JPA Repository returns null outside @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I am working on a solution where I wish to store some data using hibernate, while I am also using Spring Boot as a framework.
When I wish to use call any of the methods that the CRUDRepository provides I get into trouble. I am able to successfully call them from the API-Controller class with no problem, however, when I attempt the same from another class (annotated `@Service`) the repository returns null. To me, it seems that it's weird to have the repository interaction in the API. This is based on a Separation of Concerns and 3-layer architecture standpoint.

I have a suspicion that Spring might be messing with me and only allowing such calls inside beans?

Repository:

```java
package com.BrewMES.demo.Persistence;
import ...

@Repository
public interface MachineRepository extends CrudRepository<Machine, UUID> {
}
```

Service Interface:

```java
package com.BrewMES.demo.Persistence;
import ...

public interface MachineService {
    void saveMachine(Machine machine);
}
```

Service:

```java
package com.BrewMES.demo.Persistence;
import ...

@Service
public class MachineServiceImpl implements MachineService {
    @Autowired
    private MachineRepository repo;

    @Override
    public void saveMachine(Machine machine) {
        System.out.println("Ye get here ye?");
        repo.save(machine);
    }
}
```

Layers:

[image]

Comment: Who is calling `MachineServiceImpl` from where when you run into problems?

Comment: what does the machine object look like?

Comment: Imma go out on a limp here and suggest you remove the `field injection` and switch over to `constructor` injection. `null` injected values during runtime signify that something may have gone wrong during the construction of the required `bean` (in your case the `repository`). Switching over to constructor based injection will result in a much clearer error than the `null` you see.

Comment: @Smutje That would be the class BrewMES in the model package

Comment: @Aman its just a regular class with some variables, anything specific you're curious about?

Comment: So what does BrewMES looks like?

Comment: What do you mean by *the repository returns null*, is it that the field itself is null?

Comment: @Smutje It is simply annotated with @Service and then contains a variable 
```
 @Autowired
 private MachineRepository repo;
```

Comment: @Aman I mean that the program crashed because of null pointer exception whenever i try to get the count, or content of the database table. (Yes i checked that its not empty).

Comment: My question went into the direction of "where is the original request coming from", that's why adding *every* piece of relevant code is required to help usually. If BrewMES is just another service, who calls BrewMES then?

Comment: @Smutje Sorry, i see where you're getting now. That is done from BrewMesApplication which is the autogenerated main class from spring.